# Crystal reports limited to three concurrent user requests

Tags: java, crystal-reports, licensing, crystal-reports-xi

I have a CrystalReports XI Developer Full Product (Release 1) license and found out recently that it has a [limitation on the number of concurrent requests it can process](http://neverknewthat.wordpress.com/tag/crystal-reports-server/).

The SAP website isn't very useful and I could not find a list of products/features/limitations/cost that I could consult for more details.

Does someone know what are the upgrading options in order not to be limited anymore to three simultaneous requests?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: The programming answer to the question is: [set the `PrintJobLimit` in the registry to a number larger than 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29232245/8655).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you contact your local Crystal Reports salesman and ask.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called **concurrent processing licensing**.  I can't seem to find specific information for CR XI release 1, but this article may be helpful:

[Crystal Reports XI Release 2 - Component Licensing Explained](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/boc/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/804acc00-8364-2b10-b995-de99ca43c403?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found the document you posted useful, but do you know of any list of licenses/products that I could upgrade to (the SAP site isn't very useful :( )

Answer (score 0):

If your needs are small, Crystal Reports Server will run you $2500 or so per 5 users. You can get this from CDW and the likes.

If you have huge "enterprise" reporting needs, you'll need the Crystal Enterprise product which will run you $100k to $1M plus.

If you want an alternate solution to run Crystal Reports on the web with no user limitation, check out Report Runner Web Portal:

http://www.reportrunner.com